# Is there a way to create elements that looks like tags?

Tags: graphics, formatting

How can I style some element that looks like stackoverflow tags?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This can be easily done with TikZ or alike. Please see the PGF manual and try to construct them. If you encounter any problems, post you code here with your specific question and we try to help you. Like this, it is just a "do-it-for-me"-question which will not find much interest here.

Comment: tex does not have "elements" are you asking about a web page (with mathjax style math as on math.stackexchange?) (If so it is off topic for this site)

Comment: `tcolorbox` could be another solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another option using [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{tagbg}{RGB}{224,234,241}
\definecolor{tagtext}{RGB}{62,109,154}

\newtcbox{\mytag}{
  enhanced,
  nobeforeafter,
  tcbox raise base,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
  top=1pt,
  bottom=1pt,
  right=3pt,
  left=3pt,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
  before upper={\vphantom{dlg}},
  coltext=tagtext,
  colback=tagbg,
  colframe=tagtext,
  fontupper=\sffamily
}

\begin{document}

\mytag{html}
\mytag{css}
\mytag{alignment}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

With `\fcolorbox` command from the `xcolor` package you can define a new command `\tagbox`

```
\newcommand{\tagbox}[1]{\fcolorbox{LightGray}{LightCyan}{\textsf{#1}}}
```

Change the colors to the ones you like.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\tagbox}[1]{\fcolorbox{LightGray}{LightCyan}{\textsf{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\tagbox{html}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

Just to show that it can be done without `tcolorbox`.

MWE (colors borrowed from [Gonzalo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222954/27635)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% colors borrowed from Gonzalo's answer
\definecolor{TagBG}{RGB}{224,234,241}
\definecolor{TagText}{RGB}{62,109,154}

\newcommand{\tagbox}[1]{\fcolorbox{TagText}{TagBG}{\textcolor{TagText}{\textsf{\vphantom{hg}#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\tagbox{html} \tagbox{css} \tagbox{alignment}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]